# To find explicit formula for $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ for the equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let the two equations $x=e^u \cos v$, $y=e^u \sin v$ defines $u=u(x,y)$ and $v=v(x,y)$.
>
> Find the explicit formulas for $u=u(x,y)$ and $v=v(x,y)$ when $x>0$.

How should I find the explicit formulas for the equations? Should I use implicit function theorem? I am not getting the appropriate method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$x^2+y^2=e^{2u}\cos^2 v+e^{2u}\sin^2 v=e^{2u}(\cos^2 v+\sin^2 v)=e^{2u},$$ from where $$e^u=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ and $$u=\ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

On the other hand $$\frac y x=\frac{e^u\sin v}{e^u\cos v}=\tan v.$$ Thus, $$v=\arctan \frac yx.$$